# Is this a duplicate tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

[Here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tags?page=9&tab=popular) on page 9 of the tags list, there's a tag named "foundamental-astronomy", which seems to be a duplicate of "fundamental-astronomy". The tag description is the same, and when I click on it, it goes to questions with the "fundamental-astronomy" tag.

Is it a duplicate? Or possibly an alternative (British?) spelling? Should we remove it, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

The tag [foundamental-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foundamental-astronomy) has been marked as a synonym of [fundamental-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fundamental-astronomy). Users can't actually use "foundamental astronomy" - everything automatically routes, corrects, and or renames to [fundamental-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fundamental-astronomy).

Comment: Okay but it begs the question of why it exists then.

Comment: No idea. Perhaps someone kept using it, so the synonym was added.